# Can a positive elementary inductive definition refer to its own stage comparison relation?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, finite-model-theory, model-theory

Moschovakis' stage comparison theorem says that the *stage comparison relation* associated with any positive elementary induction is itself definable by (another) positive elementary induction. But what if we augmented a positive elementary induction by the ability to refer to its own stage-comparison relation, at least with regards to elements that already appear at some prior stage of the induction? Is the resulting least fixed-point still inductive?

Formally: Suppose $\varphi(x,R,S)$ is a first-order formula in a signature $L$ with *two* second-order variables: a unary relation symbol $S$ and a binary relation symbol $R$. Suppose $R$ and $S$ each only appear positively in $\varphi$ (i.e., under an even number of negations).

I will define ordinal-indexed families of unary relations $S^\alpha$ and binary relations $R^\alpha$ on that structure as follows:

- $S^0 := \emptyset$
- $R^\alpha(x,y)$ means ``there is some $\iota < \jmath \le \alpha$ such that $x \in S^\iota$, $y \in S^\jmath$, and $y \notin S^\ell$ for any $\ell < \jmath$.''
- $S^{\alpha + 1} := \{x:\varphi(x,R^\alpha,S^\alpha)\}$, and
- For limit ordinals $\gamma$, $S^\gamma := \bigcup_{\alpha < \gamma} S^\alpha$.

(All definitions are with respect to a fixed implicit $L$-structure)

I claim that the sequence $S^\alpha$ is monotone in $\alpha$. (Note that monotonicity of $R^\alpha$ follows immediately from definition of $R$.) Let's prove by induction on $\beta$ that for all $\alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha \subseteq S^\beta$. At successor stages ($\beta = \delta + 1$) it suffices to observe that $S^\delta \subseteq S^{\delta + 1}$: if $x \in S^\delta$ then $\varphi(x,R^\alpha,S^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \le \delta$, so $x \in S^{\delta + 1}$ as both $R$ and $S$ occur positively in $\varphi$. For limit ordinals $\beta$ and $\alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha \subseteq S^\beta$ immediately by definition of $S^\beta$.

Since $S^\alpha$ is monotone in $\alpha$, there is some least ordinal (the *closure ordinal*) $\Gamma$ such that $S^\alpha$ stabilizes past $\Gamma$ (i.e., for all $\Gamma \le \alpha < \beta$, $S^\alpha = S^\beta$). At this point, $R^\Gamma$ is just the stage comparison relation associated with this induction.

**Question:** Is $S^\Gamma$ inductive? I.e., is there a positive elementary $L$-formula $\psi(x,T)$ such that the least fixed-point of $\psi$ is $S^\Gamma$?

(I'd guess that if the answer is *yes,* then we should be able to find such a $\psi$ that's independent of the underlying $L$-structure, though I have no good reason for that.)

Comment: You introduce $\varphi$ as a binary symbol (it takes $x$ and $S$) but then later on you use it as a unary symbol (you write $\varphi(\varphi^\alpha)$. What's going on?

Comment: In a nutshell: currying. In general $S$ is a $n$-ary relation symbol and $x$ is a $n$-tuple of variables, for some $n$. Then by $\varphi(S)$ I mean $\{x : \varphi(x,S)\}$.

Comment: Just to check: are you fixing the underlying language to be the language of arithmetic?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm wondering if this holds for arbitrary first-order structures (the setting of the original stage comparison theorem). But if there are solutions for particular cases, I'm interested in that too.

Comment: Okay. Also, can you perhaps edit the question to be more precise about the definition of the operator $\varphi(X,R)$ ($X$ unary, $R$ binary in place of $\prec$)? It's still unclear to me how precisely you are seeing this as a monotone operator.

Comment: Done (at last).